# Ionic 4 Camera plugin - Image size after saving compressed image to photo album

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, cordova-plugins

I am trying to compress image using camera plugin in ionic 4. I used below code for compression:

```
const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 30,
      cameraDirection: 1,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      sourceType: source,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
      correctOrientation: true,
      targetWidth: 500,
      targetHeight: 800
    };
```

I used file plugin to check size of the image and it is showing 15627 but in albums the saved image size is 3MB. I tried to change `quality: 100` and the file plugin is showing 223727 but the saved image in albums is still have size 3MB.

Do you guys have any idea how it works ? What should be the size of saved image in album ?

Comment: Try FILE_URI: `destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI` and Check Result.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This.

this.camera.getPicture({
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  sourceType: sourceType,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: (source === PictureSource.CAMERA),
  allowEdit: true
})
  .then(imageUri => {
    this.imageResizer.resize({
      uri: imageUri,
      quality: 60,
      width: 500,
      height: 800
    }).then(uri => handler(uri))
  })
  .catch(error => console.warn(error))
```